# In price rules, lookup query Tested field not showing "CurrencyIsoCode" value

Tags: cpq, steelbrick, lookup-field, pricerule

[image]

dev sandbox able to see, when trying create full copy it is not visible. How to populate lookup field value  "CurrencyIsoCode" in TestedField

Appreciate your help

Comment: Is Multicurrency turned on in the full copy and in production?

Comment: Yes, #David Multicurrency turned  on

Comment: what is "Tested Field" in price rules and product rules, how we can add picklist values for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested Field is just a picklist field on SBQQ__LookupQuery__c object. If you want to have an additional value, you need to manually add an API name of desired field from Quote, Quote Line or Product Option. Regarding the currency, we don't know the context of all process in your org so the best approach will be to review the usual hints of multi-currencies implementation provided by [SF](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318346&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)